# VBA loop to repeat an Excel Calc over multiple row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, rows

Evening Boffins,

I think I have what you will find a relatively easy question.

I would like to repeat the excel calc below on circa 200 rows in excel and sum the result;

```
=IF('By Project'!$AM$40>0.01,'By Project'!$AM$40*'By Project'!G$40,0)
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks
Newbie

Comment: Do you mean that you want the formula to then calculate row 41, then row 42, then etc for 200 rows?  what cell is your formula going in?Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: If you just remove the $ from the row then fill down, you can sum the results.

Comment: Yes exactly that I want to repeat the calc. I need the whole 200 calcs to be summed in a single cell

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(AM1:AM200>0.01),(AM1:AM200*G1:G200))
```

Comment: excuse my ignorance but where does my if statement fit into the formula?

Comment: `AM1:AM400>0.01` is the part checking for values > 0.01